# Complex layout with Relative and inside a TextView wrong size

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

i'm creating a relative layout programatically, trying to first draw most right element and then place others left each other.

This is my code (Simplified)

```
    Stream.of(columns)
                    .custom(new Reverse<>())
                    .reduceIndexed(new View(context), (index, identity, accumulator) -> {
                        View previous = identity;

                        View columnView = cardColumnRenderer.render(accumulator);
                        columnView.setId(ViewIdGenerator.Companion.getRandomId());
                        addView(columnSetLayout, index, previous, columnView);

                        return columnView;
                    });

private void addView(RelativeLayout columnSetLayout, int index, View previousView, View viewToInsert) {
        if (index == 0) {
            LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) viewToInsert.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            columnSetLayout.addView(viewToInsert);
        } else {
            LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) viewToInsert.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, previousView.getId());
            columnSetLayout.addView(viewToInsert, layoutParams);
        }
    }
```

CardColumnRenderer.render() will render a RelativeLayout with a textview inside.

My problem is, right element parent (RelativeLayout) fills almost width of the parent container, even child textview has the real size measured, for example, RelativeLayout has 808px but child only has 300 and both are Wrap_Content..

Any idea..?